# Why would I need extra IP addresses from my web host?

Tags: web-hosting, server

I am moving to a new and cheaper host. My old one raised the prices suddenly by a factor 10. Now what I did not like about the old one was that each time I set up a new website, I had to set up a new account. The result was that I have to pay for a lot of web space and a lot of bandwidth that I don't use.

Now I am moving over to a new host, who cheaply offers virtual servers. Now I am a n00b when it comes to server tech.

I have two questions about this:

1. Could I install all my websites on this virtual server, provided it is big enough?
2. They offer the possibility of getting more than one IP address, but it costs more. What would be the advantage of this? Would I be able to suffice with one IP address?

Comment: "I am a n00b when it comes to server tech." - Then you should really consider getting a web hosting reseller account instead - setting up a server securely and getting everything working is a serious amount of work.

Answer (score 2):

1) Sure. Just compare the amount of space your sites take up (be sure to include the size of your databases) and make sure your new host has allocated that much space for you.

2) If you plan on using SSL for any of your websites you will need a unique IP address for each secure site for SSL to work.